# SQL nvarchar Formatting

Tags: sql, format, nvarchar

So i have a Datatype nvarchar which is a Phone number its currently in the format of (123)456-7891 but i want it to be 1234567891 no Brackets or any thing. Some of the Numbers have words in front like ABC(123)456-7891 << This format so its a nvarchar that allows number and Letter but i want the Format of the number to be without any Special words ()-- how can i convert it i have tried.

```
FORMAT(cast( PhoneNumber as numeric),'##########') as PhoneNumber
```

It saves the Procedure properly but when i try to excute it it says `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric` 
i tried only `FORMAT(PhoneNumber,'##########`), 
but it says `Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.`
I cant get it to work please let me know if you know any thing about it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you also want to remove `ABC` too?

Comment: No I don't i just what the Numbers and the ABC with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `replace()`:

```
select replace(replace(replace(PhoneNumber, '-', ''), ')', ''), '(', '')
```

You cannot convert a string that contains `'('`s, `')'`s, and `'-'`s to a number.

Comment: Thank You very much. that did the Trick but some how it is not replacing the Spaces how do i get ride of the Spaces too

Comment: Add another replace() around what gordon has provided, Replace(Gordon'sGreatReplace, ' ', ''). Notice the first ' ' has a space.

Comment: replace(replace(replace( replace(PhoneNumber,'-',''),')',''), '(',''),')','')
I have this but still Spaces between first 3 numbers and the rest is ok

Comment: @Haseeb.A . . . Then add another `replace()` to get rid of the space.